# Pointer Scanning in memory hacking

Tags: algorithm, assembly, memory, pseudocode, cheat-engine

if you not familiar with Pointer Scanning please read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926739/how-do-game-trainers-change-an-address-in-memory-thats-dynamic)

i have while using cheat-engine to find static address in game or any programme
using a Pointer Scanning method now i start thinking of make in my own trainer so after some search i find this:
**pseudocode**

```
list<int> pointerScan(target, maxAdd, maxDepth) {
     for address = BASE, 0x7FFFFFF, 4 {
        ret = rScan(address, target, maxAdd, maxDepth, 1)
        if (ret.len > 0) {
            ret.pushFront(address)
            return ret
        }
    }
    return {}
}

list<int> rScan(address, target, maxAdd, maxDepth, curDepth) 
{
    for offset = 0, maxAdd, 4 
    {
        value = read(address + offset)
        if (value == target)
            return list<int>(offset)
    }
     if (curDepth < maxDepth) 
     {
        curDepth++
        for offset = 0, maxAdd, 4 
        {
            ret = rScan(address + offset, target, maxAdd, maxDepth, curDepth)
            if (ret.len > 0) 
            {
                ret.pushFront(offset)
                { 
                return ret
                }
            }
        }
        return {}
    }
}
```

target is the dynamic memory address to find

maxAdd is the maximum value of any offset

maxDepth is the maximum length of the pointer path

**pointerScan()**
The `pointerScan()` function is the entry point to the scan. It takes the parameters target (the dynamic memory address to find), maxAdd (the maximum
value of any offset), and maxDepth (the maximum length of the pointer path).
It then loops through every 4-byte aligned address  in the game, calling
`rScan()` with the parameters address (the address in the current iteration),
target, maxAdd, maxDepth, and curDepth (the depth of the path, which is always 1
in this case).

**rScan()**
The `rScan()` function reads memory from every 4-byte aligned offset between
0 and maxAdd  , and returns if a result is equal to target  . If `rScan()` doesn’t
return in the frst loop and the recursion is not too deep  , it increments
curDepth and again loops over each offset  , calling itself for each iteration.

my problem with this pseudocode is i could not understand why `address + offset` in

```
ret = rScan(address + offset, target, maxAdd, maxDepth, curDepth)
```

i think has no effect
some tell me that increasing the depth but i could not see the point from increasing address because the  first function  (pointerScan)  loop over all address that align in 4 byte

Comment: Where did you find this, maybe there's some clue from context of the surrounding text?  Looks weird to me, I can't see what that's doing that they couldn't do more easily with a simple loop that stops after `n` matches or something.  (But it doesn't even check farther if the first loop finds something).  I don't think it's considering the possibility of finding misaligned pointers or anything.

Comment: @PeterCordes i edit it

Comment: src code from the book "GAME HACKING Developing Autonomous
Bots for Online Games" by Nick Cano, listing 1-1

Comment: @JavaMan ya but the book didn't explain it that much that's why

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question after looked the code and i think it should be changed to:

```
list<int> rScan(address, target, maxAdd, maxDepth, curDepth) 
{
    value = read(address)
    for offset = 0, maxAdd, 4 
    {
        if (value + offset == target)
            return list<int>(offset)
    }
     if (curDepth < maxDepth) 
     {
        curDepth++
        for offset = 0, maxAdd, 4 
        {
            ret = rScan(value + offset, target, maxAdd, maxDepth, curDepth)
            if (ret.len > 0) 
            {
                ret.pushFront(offset)
                { 
                return ret
                }
            }
        }
        return {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, consider adding explainations in order to describe how your solution solves the problem.